# Facebook app giving 404 error

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

My FB app is giving me 404 error. The method is a "get" instead of "post". So I think this is not recognized by the server. Please tell me how to change this method to post in FB application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you browse to your url outside of facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to browse through your URL directly ?

If it is then you gotta change the configuration!

Can you give the script where it has to be modified!